# Slick slider нужна помощь?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Ребят, есть вот такой вертикальный слайдер сделанный на Slick.

Проблема в том, что высота нашей пагинации ограничена. Например у нас сейчас есть пять слайдов, в пагинацию помещается только 4. То-есть если мы пролистываем до пятого слайда, в пагинации это не отображается, она остается на месте. Можно как-то сделать, чтобы когда мы переключали слайдер на пятый слайд, пагинация тоже делал слайд и переключалась.

https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/xpYLKZ

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slider__item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slider__item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slider__item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slider__item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
         <div class="slider__item"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
  <div class="slider__nav">
    <div class="slider__prev">Up</div>
    <div class="slider__next">Down</div>
  </div>
</div>

 $('.slider-wrap').slick({
   dots: true,
   arrows: false,
   vertical: true,
   verticalSwiping: true,
   customPaging: function(slider, i) {
   var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data();
   return '<a>'+(i+1)+'</a>';
  },
});
```

Comment: если у вас кастом пагинация, то и рулить ей надо соответственно. начните с понимая того, как должно происходить перелистывание. допустим у вас 8 слайдов, влезает 4. что должно показываться при переходе на 5й?  2-5  или 5-8 к примеру? При кликах вперед назад смотрите какой слайд, и скрывайте/показывайте блоки

Comment: 2-5 должно появляется. если листаем вниз, первый уходит вверх, пятый появляется

Comment: Как вариант, можно сделать две зависимые карусели. На сайте плагина, в документации, описывается, как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вариант ...

```js
$(function() {
  $(".slider__item").each(function(i) {
    $("<div><h3>" + ++i + "</h3></div>").appendTo(".slider-nav");
  });
  $(".slider-wrap").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    asNavFor: ".slider-nav",
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true
  });
  $(".slider-nav").slick({
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: ".slider-wrap",
    nextArrow: ".slider__next",
    prevArrow: ".slider__prev",
    focusOnSelect: true
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.slider-wrap {
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider__item {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.nav {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav .slider-nav {
  margin-top: 48px;
}

.slider-nav.slick-vertical div.slick-slide {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-nav.slick-vertical .slick-current {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.slider__prev,
.slider__next {
  width: 48px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider__prev {
  top: 0;
}

.slider__next {
  top: 255px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <div class="slider__item">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <div class="slider__item">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <div class="slider__item">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <div class="slider__item">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <div class="slider__item">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="slider__prev">Up</div>
    <div class="slider-nav"></div>
    <div class="slider__next">Down</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: супер, очень вам признателен